# Access a Label object from a Panel, all within a ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label, panel

I am trying to move a Label object from a Panel object, in this case I have a parent panel that has Panel and Label objects as child, these are dynamically created. The objective is that when executing from the ToolStripMenuItem, when the Panel object is moved, the Label object is also moved.

I made the following code, but I think I could not move the Label object. From what I understand, what I am doing is generating the variable that is called the same as the Label that I need, but what I need is to refer to the existing object, not the new one. (this is correct?)

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click

    Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
    clickedPanel.Location = New Point((clickedPanel.Location.X + 120), clickedPanel.Location.Y)

    Dim posX = clickedPanel.Location.X + 120
    Dim posY = clickedPanel.Location.Y

    Dim namelabel As New Label With {
        .Name = "Label" & clickedPanel.Name.Last
    }

    namelabel.Location = New Point((posX), posY)

End Sub
```

Could you please guide me?

**Note: I Forgot something, in this case, If I move the Panel1, Label1 will move too, if I move Panel2, Label2 will move too, etc, etc.**

Comment: Why don't you create a UserControl that has a Panel and a Label child controls? This way, you'll have to move just one container (of course it's children will follow :). Anyway, if you want to create simple *relation* between these two controls, you can add the reference of the *associated* Label to the related Panel's Tag property. Or you can use a Dictionary. O a `List(Of class)`, where, in each class object, you store the references of the *linked* controls. (Yes, this: `Dim namelabel As New Label` is a new Control, it's useless)

Comment: @Jimi, thank you so much for your answer. Do what you said, more simple, generate the Label inside the panel, when moving it both move without needing to generate more code. I appreciate the effort and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the code, where the label is created inside the panel dynamically, and move together.**

```
Private Sub NavButton15_ElementClick(sender As Object, e As NavElementEventArgs) Handles NavButton15.ElementClick

        Dim pos As Int32 = 50
        Dim poslabel As Int16 = 26
        Dim posY As Int16 = 330
        Dim posX As Int16 = 3
        Dim counter as Int16 = 1

        Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, 0)

        Dim pb As New Panel With
        {
            .Width = 120,
            .Height = 460,
            .Top = 10,
            .Left = 10,
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Example.bmp"),
            .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
            .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpSection,
            .Name = "Panel" & counter
        }

        Dim labela As New Label With {
                    .AutoSize = True,
                    .Location = New Point((poslabel), 12),
                    .Text = "Panel " & counter,
                    .ForeColor = Color.White,
                    .BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                    .Font = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                    .Name = "Label" & counter
                }

        pb.Location = New Point(pos, 20)

        Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)
        pb.Controls.Add(labela)

    End Sub
```

**This is the ToolStripMenuItem where move the panel whit the label.**

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
    clickedPanel.Location = New Point((clickedPanel.Location.X + 120), clickedPanel.Location.Y)

End Sub
```